# How can I pause/stop a mesh animation in DirectX9?

Tags: c++, directx, mesh

Does DirectX 9 have a function that will stop or pause a mesh's animation that is currently running? I need an example on how the function works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example in the DirectX SDK on how to do it using the X-File format and D3DX classes.  More info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee418800(VS.85).aspx

Comment: i know how to display a mesh but i can't get it to stop when i want it to. im i missing something?

Comment: @Ramiz: Well what animation system are you using.  What code have you got already?  In my animation system I call "mpAnimation->Stop();" but thats probably not much help to you ;)  Your question is rather lacking in information...

Comment: Btw assuming you are using ID3DXAnimationController you could just try NOT calling "AdvanceTime" ...

Comment: i don't like sdk examples about meshes most of the code is useless for me they create combo boxes...

Comment: @Ramiz:  Its your loss in the end.  Your biggest issue is that not many people use D3DX meshes due to the D3D tie in ... Your options for examples are limited ...